# Find the Prime Factorization of $\varphi(11!)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

> Find the Prime Factorization of $\varphi(11!)$

What I did:

$\varphi(11!)=\varphi(11)\cdot\varphi(10)...\varphi(1)$

$$\varphi(11)=2\cdot 5\\
\varphi(10)=2^2\\
\varphi(9)=3\cdot 2\\
\varphi(8)=2^2\\
\varphi(7)=2\cdot 3\\
\varphi(6)=2\\
\varphi(5)=2^2\\
\varphi(4)=2\\
\varphi(3)=2\\
$$

$$\Longrightarrow\text{ the answer is }  2^{12}\cdot 5\cdot 3^2$$

[$11!$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11!)

[$\varphi(11!)=\varphi(39916800)=8294400$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=phi(39916800))

[$8294400=2^{12}3^45^2$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8294400)

Where am I wrong?

Is there a simpler way to solve this?

Comment: $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(a)$ if $a$ and $b$ are coprime ! and for exemple $3$ and $6$ are not coprime.

Comment: Euler's totient function is not multiplicative unless the factors are coprime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
  & \bigg\lfloor \frac{11}{2} \bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor \frac{11}{4} \bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor \frac{11}{8} \bigg\rfloor=8 \\ 
 & \bigg\lfloor \frac{11}{3} \bigg\rfloor+\bigg\lfloor \frac{11}{9} \bigg\rfloor=4 \\ 
 & \bigg\lfloor \frac{11}{5} \bigg\rfloor=2 \\ 
 & \bigg\lfloor \frac{11}{7} \bigg\rfloor=1 \\ 
 &\bigg\lfloor \frac{11}{11} \bigg\rfloor=1 \\ 
\end{align}
$$\varphi(11!)=\varphi ({{2}^{8}}\times {{3}^{4}}\times {{5}^{2}}\times {{7}^{1}}\times {{11}^{1}})=\varphi ({{2}^{8}})\varphi ({{3}^{4}})\varphi ({{5}^{2}})\varphi ({{7}^{1}})\varphi ({{11}^{1}})$$
Note if $P$ be prime then
$$\varphi(P^n)=P^n-P^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 4):

While it is true that you should exploit the fact that $\varphi$ is multiplicative, what you do is not quite correct.

Recall that $\varphi(nm)= \varphi(n) \varphi(m)$ needs that $m$ and $n$ are co-prime.

Thus, first write $11!$ as a product of distinct prime powers. Only, then do what you did.

Answer (score 3):

$\varphi(11!)=(11!) (1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{3}) (1-\frac{1}{5}) (1-\frac{1}{7}) (1-\frac{1}{11})$. I do not really know if this will help.