# How many natural numbers $x\leqslant 21 !$ there are such that $\gcd(x,20!)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> How many natural numbers $x\leqslant 21 !$ there are such that $\gcd(x,20!)=1$

*Attempt:*

I used [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1847701/306803) methode and I have found that:

[$21!$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=51090942171709440000)$=2^{18}\times3^{9}\times5^{4}\times7^{3}\times11\times13\times17\times19$

[$20!$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2432902008176640000)$=2^{18}\times3^{\color{red}8}\times5^{4}\times7^{\color{red}2}\times11\times13\times17\times19$

It's easy to see that the prime factorization contains the same prime numbers, but how can I know how many numbers $x\leqslant 21 !$ there are such that $\gcd(x,20!)=1$

---

If I look at $3$ and $3^2$, so there are $4$ numbers between $3$ and $9$ such that $\gcd(3,x)=1$ $3,\color{blue}4,\color{blue}5,6,\color{blue}7,\color{blue}8,9$

Comment: No, tell us first how many natural numbers $x\leqslant\color{red}{20!}$ are there such that $\gcd(x,20!)=1$.

Comment: Let $n$ be the product of the primes up to 20. Can you work out how many numbers up to $n$ are relatively prime to $n$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin $\varphi(20!)$?

Comment: That's right. Now add $20!$ to all these numbers. That would not change the gcd. Therefore the interval $(20!,2\cdot20!)$ contains exactly as much numbers that we want. Ditto for $(2\cdot20!,3\cdot20!)$, and so on...

Comment: I will be happy to get a full answer from someone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily notice that for a natural number $n$, gcd$(n,20!)=1$ if and only if gcd$(n,21!)=1$. Thus you can ask the question as follows :

How many natural numbers $x\leq 21!$ such that gcd($x,21!)=1$. Then the answer is $\varphi(21!)$ which is easy to calculate.

Comment: @KushalBhuyan: You're comparing the wrong numbers. You should be comparing the number of numbers coprime to $3!$ up to $4!$ and the number of numbers coprime to $4!$ up to $4!$, and these are both eight.

Comment: May be I understood the question wrongly @joriki

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I think the question is clear.